# Using facebook-sdk to publish in a user's "news feed"

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-timeline

Folks, I'm trying to publish a message to an user's "news feed" using facebook-sdk with little success. The following code is only able to publish to the user's wall. I want to publish it to the user's news feed (timeline).

```
graph.put_object("me", "feed", message='some text')
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The user's wall is now knows as the user's timeline. The same API call will work for publishing to the timeline. Posts published to the user's timeline / news feed will appear on friends' news feed depending on Facebook algorithms and the popularity of the post.

If this isn't what you are after, lease rephrase the question to be more specific / clear.